# Minimal working IteratorProtocol / Sequence in Swift 3

Tags: iterator, swift3, sequence

I've found it remarkably difficult to find "working documentation" for using Sequence / IteratorProtocol in Swift 3.  The few tutorials/articles out there seem to be for older Swift.

Imagine a toy doubly-linked list class called `DLList` ...

```
public class Node
    {
    // whatever "thing" you have a group of, this is that "thing"
    }
public class DLList
    {
    // toy linked list class here
    // so this is a group of "node" in this example
    }
```

I believe the following represents the simplest (?), correct, way to make it that you can, in a word, use `DLList` in a `for` structure.

## Step 1, make your DLList conform to DLList:Sequence

```
public class DLList:Sequence
    {
    // toy linked list class here
    
    public func makeIterator() -> DLListIterator
        {
        return DLListIterator(self)
        }
    }
```

It would seem that all you have to do is add the `makeIterator` call.

## Step 2, write your iterator, conforms to `IteratorProtocol`

Since the class is DLList, we'll call it DLListIterator. It would seem that

1, you have to have an "init" which basically takes the group class in question

2, you have to have a `next` call, which must return one of the "things" which are magically related to your group class.

```
public class DLListIterator:IteratorProtocol
    {
    var dll:DLList  // you must know the group in question
    var pointer:Node?  // you must know where you are
    
    init(_ dll:DLList)
        {
        // so note those two items
        self.dll = dll
        self.pointer = dll.firstOne
        }
    
    public func next() -> Node?
        {
        // return the next one; careful to return nil at end.
        let thisOne = self.pointer
        self.pointer = self.pointer?.nextOne
        return thisOne
        }
    }
```

This does seem to work perfectly. ie, you can now go

```
var d:DLList = DLList()
for n in d
 {
 print or whatever n
 }
```

you can use `e = d.filter( {d.item blah} )` and so on - great.

**Question** - there's a lot of talk about **associated types**. In part 1, do you somehow explicitly state/add the "associated type"? Even if it's not explicitly required **how would you do that** explicitly? What the hell is this associated type business?

**Question** - in part two I'm completely mystified how it "knows" that Node is the "thing" that relates to DLList.  Is there a way to make that explicit, or what am I not understanding?

**Swiftness** Moreover, the whole thing seems not very Swifty.  It seems incredible to do all that just to add iterator output.  In Swift3 is there a snappier way, for a real class?  (Not a silly example like "countdown numbers".)

**Final question** I cheerfully mention that the above now allows for and .filter.  In fact, is my example "complete" - can I now do everything "iterator-wise" with DLList, that one can do normally in Swift - have I perhaps "forgotten some features" or ??  Is there more to do in making DLList a really good iterator?

Comment: Worth noting that if you don't need a seperate type for the iterator, and the logic to iterate is relatively simple, you can just make use of `AnyIterator` (I have no idea if that qualifies as 'more Swifty' to you) – see for example [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/7590054d4eb8d05067d356c507fb706a).

Comment: @Hamish - got it, I guess that's the shortcut, thanks.  Nice use of `defer`. What a perfect gist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all nicely works via type inference (really strong thing in Swift).

E.g. `IteratorProtocol` has only one requirement, that is `next() -> Element?` method.  Here is what you can see if you just Cmd-click on `IteratorProtocol` in XCode:

```
public protocol IteratorProtocol {
    associatedtype Element
    public mutating func next() -> Self.Element?
}
```

So if you declare a type to conform to `IteratorProtocol` and provide an implementation of some `next() -> Foo?` then Swift immediately infers that `Foo` must be an `Element`.

You can, of course, make an explicit declaration via:

```
public class DLListIterator: IteratorProtocol {
    public typealias Element = Node

    public func next() -> Element? {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And, yes, once you implemented both (`Sequence` and `Iterator`, that is) you can do everything that other Sequences can do.  All this thanks to default protocol implementations.

Whether all this boilerplate that in order to conform to `Sequence` you need to provide `makeIterator()`, that in turn has to provide a `next()`, is Swifty or not..  I think this is something more of opinion-based.  Sometimes, you can implement `Sequence` without going down to implementing `IteratorProtocol` (e.g. when you implement a wrapper).  So, the split does make sense to me.

Comment: holy crap!  can you help me understand what `Element` is ?  Is that something defined in `IteratorProtocol`?  Or is it a standard type in Swift, or??  Thanks!

Comment: @JoeBlow, `Element` is an associated type with `IteratorProtocol` (see the edit).

Answer (score 5):

this is my min example

```
class TestIter: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    var mylist:[Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]    // contents
    var curPos = 0                      // var for iterator

    func makeIterator() -> TestIter {
        curPos = 0
        return self
    }

    public typealias Element = Int
    func next() -> Element? {
        if curPos < mylist.count {
            let oldPos = curPos
            curPos += 1
            return mylist[oldPos]
        }
        return nil
    }

}

let testIt = TestIter()
for i in testIt {
    print("i:\(i)")
}
```

Comment: This is an almost exact copy of the sample included in the Apple documentation and does not include any mention of the makeIterator() function.