# Swift 3 - Making class iterable

Tags: arrays, swift, collections, iterator, sequence

Consider my two classes:

```
// Person.swift
class Person {
    var parents: Parents?
    // ...
}

// Parents.swift. Only a collection of parents with some helper methods.
class Parents {
    var parents = [Person]()
    // ...
}
```

How could I make `Parents` iterate in a for loop using the iterators of `parents`. This is not a real world app. I'm just curious. Just would like to use `for parent in myParents` instead of `for parent in myParents.parents`.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350731/minimal-working-iteratorprotocol-sequence-in-swift-3?rq=1

Comment: @ApriOri You don't even need to conform to `IteratorProtocol` since you're essentially building a wrapper around an `Array`. You just need to expose the underlying `Sequence` Protocol.

Comment: I'm surprised this question and answer don't have more upvotes. A. this seems like a fairly common need (to iterate a wrapped array), and B. conforming to Sequence protocol (and friends) is anything but intuitive.

Answer (score 7):

The way to do this is to have your `Parents` class conform to the [`Sequence` Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence), implement a `makeIterator` method, and then pass the result through from calling `makeIterator` on the contained `Array<Person>`

```
  // Person.swift
  class Person {
    var parents: Parents?
    // ...
  }

  // Parents.swift. Only a collection of parents with some helper methods.
  class Parents{
    var parents = [Person]()
    // ...
  }

  // conform to Sequence Protocol
  extension Parents: Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> Array<Person>.Iterator {
      return parents.makeIterator()
    }
  }

  let myself = Person()
  if let myParents = myself.parents {
    for person in myParents {

    }
  }
```

Comment: You beat me by 30 seconds, so I up voted yours instead.  The only difference is that I had declared `makeIterator` as `func makeIterator() -> IndexingIterator<[Person]>`.

Comment: @vacawama I prefer to just use the `Iterator` from the contained `Array` since that will always be exactly right. Filling it in directly might get out of sync if you make changes and forget to update that method. Although the compiler will probably correct you if you do just that.